# How can I change the ui-select height in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Does anybody know how can I change a select box height from a ui-select bootstrap element in Angular?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default css of the control. For example the selectize theme has the code:  `.selectize-dropdown-content` has a max-height.

Second you can use a custom theme functionality.